# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (117, 1, 32, 32, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was developing a image classification project when i got this error for fitting my model.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (117, 1, 32, 32, 3)
```

This is my code for training the dataset. It has 3 features and 117 images.

```
def create_train_dataset():
x_train = []
y_train = []
for foldername in os.listdir(train_data):
    label = map[foldername]
    for image1 in os.listdir(train_data + "/" + foldername):
        img = image.load_img(train_data + "/" + foldername + "/" + image1, target_size=(32, 32))
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        x_train.append(img)
        y_train.append(label)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')/255.0
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
print("Training Dataset Created")
return x_train, y_train
```

I thought it would have 4 dimensions but output of its shape gave :

```
Training Data Shape =  (117, 1, 32, 32, 3)
```

And so after running model fit line :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=5, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```

I got the stated error. I thought the x_train would have 4 dimensions but somehow it has 5 which gives error. Can anyone please tell why it happens and how i can correct it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of np.expand_dims(img, axis=0).

Comment: If I remove it the error is : expected 4 dimensions but got input as (117,3) . So what do I do?

Comment: weird. Does reshape work? Can you reshape to get your desired output using np.reshape? Can you reshape before passing to your network with or without expand dims?

Comment: Actually something weird happens(not talking about reshape). Without using expand_dims , if I print x_train it shows (117,32,32,3) but same x_train used in model fit shows error that it has (117,3) shape. Can't know what's going on?